# Ideal diode used with 2 batteries experiencing low voltage cutout

Tags: batteries, diodes

I have a mobility scooter that I upgraded the controller on. It is a 1800 watt controller. I am using two 48V 10ah Lithium batteries in parallel with 50 amp ideal diodes ( https://www.amazon.ca/Anti-Reverse-Irrigation-Protection-Resistance-Anti-backflow/dp/B08XYVZW72/ref=sr_1_6?keywords=ideal+diode+50a&sr=8-6) for each battery. Under heavy load (going uphill) my controller will cut-out, display goes out and I must power it back on. My controller manufacturer suggested that the problem is that my batteries are not able to handle the output current needed and the voltage is dropping and the BMS is cutting out. If I run the batteries in parallel without the ideal diodes this does not happen. So what I am thinking is that the ideal diodes will only allow current to be drawn from the better battery (higher voltage) and not both batteries at the same time. I was thinking that if each battery is rated for a 30 amp output and I was drawing 45 amps it would just draw 1/2 from each battery. Is this wrong?